# Check whether an element has a given element inside its mentioned class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function A(){
    $('input[name="B[]"]').each(function() { 
        if(('$(this) .BtnSet .Child input:text[name="A[]"]').length){
         //yes the Child class is inside JRow class and has textboxes with name A[]
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="return A()">
    <div class="row JRow">
     <input type="text" name="B[]"></input>
     <input type="text" name="B[]"></input>
        <div class="BtnSet">
            <div class="Child">
                <input type="text" name="A[]"></input>
                <input type="text" name="A[]"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to check whether the Child class is inside the row JRow class and if so,whether any textboxes are available with the name A[] inside the Child class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if($('.JRow .BtnSet .Child input:text[name="A[]"]').length){
    //yes the Child class is inside JRow class and has textboxes with name A[]
}
```

Comment: +1 for answering what was asked, but I'm dubious about the clarity of the question.  You need the points anyway :p

Comment: Thankzfor the reply.... If I need to check the textboxes are even inside the BtnSet class

if($('.JRow .BtnSet .Child input:text[name="A[]"]').length){
    //yes the Child class is inside JRow class and has textboxes with name A[]
}

do I need to edit it like that?

And don't I need put the whole class name "row JRow" in the code?

Comment: Dont I need to put the whole class name?

The class name is "row JRow" but you have put only JRow. Is it oki?

Comment: @Lakmini those are two classnames `row` and `JRow`, read about class selectors

Comment: @Arun: Arun I edited some parts of the code. Now I entered another set of textboxes named B[]. Now I need to check whether B[] has a BtnSet class. Inside it whether there is a Child class and inside it where there are chilren elements like A[]. Have I done it precisely?

Comment: But the problem is in this case when I print alert('$(this) .BtnSet .Child input:text[name="A[]"]').length)  the lenth is coming always as 45. Please explain me the reason for that